# DaveTheWave isn’t a new contributor; Can we do something about repeated account recreation?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, user-accounts

I thought I must be going insane, but no, [it’s not just me](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/what-kind-of-particles-are-missing-in-the-universe). Other people have noticed too that [DaveTheWave](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/51330/davethewave) keeps making new accounts. They will then post low-quality content. One they get a **reputation** for this and their new-contributor nice thing wears off then they create a new account and start all over again.

Comment: [The user has responded about this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/what-kind-of-particles-are-missing-in-the-universe#comment121251_54071), but I'd like to say for the future that if you have serious concerns about a user's behavior, please let the moderators know (rather than posting on meta). Since there's no way to flag a user themself, raise a custom flag on one of their posts with a brief explanation of your concern.

Comment: About the response…this isn’t the second time…it’s the fifth or so@HDE226868

Comment: Additionally, I wanted to bring up the larger issue as well

Comment: Still something that should be done via flags, unless this is an issue affecting a number of different people.

Comment: I feel like I’ve seen this before on SPace.SE @HDE226868

Comment: This sort of thing happens on all SE sites all the time.  The powers that be are aware of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as

> They will then post low-quality content.

I don't think that's an accurate or at least complete characterization - I think it's a little more complicated. Several of the questions in question are well received and several generate really interesting and well up-voted answers!

Despite the one-liner format for many of the user's questions which lack any evidence of prior research, a lot of these deceptively simple or naive-sounding questions turn out to be really good questions.

And some don't.

And "some do and some don't" can apply to a lot of (relatively) new users.

#### A lot going on "[under the hood](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/under_the_hood)"

I feel that there is a lot going on "under the hood" in these questions, but because they only show the bottom line and don't include any clues how they got to this point, some folks can't see what it is that makes these questions so interesting.

As pointed out under the question, the user [has responded](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/what-kind-of-particles-are-missing-in-the-universe#comment121251_54071)

> ... I don't play games...

My take is that's simply true.

My personal view is that for some of us, it takes a little longer to get used to how Stack Exchange works, or what Stack Exchange even is.

While some insist that the answers to those questions are obvious, I can assure you **it took me years to develop** my own understanding of Stack Exchange, and to finally express it as [the three lemmas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377004/303080).

I'm a "little different" and a lot of people fall into that category.

So if we feel there's an issue, we first comment and explain our concern, then if necessary we flag. But anomalous and different asking behavior does not warrant demonification.

#### [Don't Panic!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Panic:_The_Official_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_Companion)